Counting Eilenberg/Schutzenberger-type definitions of pseudovarieties
See Eilenberg/Schutzenberger, On pseudovarieties for background on pseudovarieties. I've phrased things in terms of pairs-of-sets to avoid some annoying language about multisets. Also, I'm aware that Reiterman's theorem is in many ways a better characterization of pseudovariety-hood, but it doesn't give rise to the sort of question I'm asking here.
Suppose $\mathscr{V}$ is a pseudovariety in a countable language $\Sigma$. Say that a minimal description of $\mathscr{V}$ is a pair $(E,F)$ of sets of $\Sigma$-equations such that

$\mathscr{V}$ is the set of finite $\Sigma$-algebras which satisfy all equations in $E$ and all-but-finitely-many equations in $F$; and

if $E'\subseteq E, F'\subseteq F$ are such that $(E', F')$ satisfies the previous bulletpoint, then $E'=E$ and $\vert F\setminus F'\vert<\infty$.


Two minimal descriptions $(E,F), (G,H)$ are equivalent iff $E=G$ and $F\Delta H$ is finite (where "$\Delta$" denotes the symmetric difference).

What are the possible numbers of minimal descriptions (up to equivalence) of a pseudovariety?

For example, is there a pseudovariety with exactly 3 minimal descriptions up to equivalence? More set-theoretically, is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ for there to be a pseudovariety with exactly $\aleph_1$ minimal descriptions up to equivalence?
(Re: that last question, unless I'm missing something the set $M$ of minimal descriptions of $\mathscr{V}$ is coanalytic and equivalence on that set is Borel, so by Burgess' trichotomy theorem we can't get anything strictly between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$. Specifically, view $M$ as a coanalytic subset of an appropriate Polish space $\mathcal{X}$ and consider the equivalence relation which identifies two elements of $M$ iff they are equivalent in the above sense and which collapses the whole complement of $M$ to a single class. This is analytic, so Burgess applies. I don't see how to make it coanalytic though, so Silver doesn't seem to help here.)

What’s an example of a minimal description for a pseudovariety of semigroups with F nonempty?  For instance do finite groups have a minimal description as a pseudovariety of semigroups? The schemes I’m used to always have some subsequence of identities which also define the pseudovariety.

For example if you take a basis of pseudoidentities at least one of which is not an identity and then build F by sequences converging to these pseudoidentities you can always keep taking subsequences so such a thing does not seem to contain a minimal description.

@BenjaminSteinberg (Perhaps a silly response since I'm about to go to sleep:) I don't know about finite groups. I might be having a silly moment, but for your initial question: what if we take $E=\emptyset$ and $F={\sigma_i:i\in\omega}$ where $\sigma_i$ says that we can cyclically permute any product of $i$th-prime-many elements (associated to the left, so e.g. $\sigma_3$ says $(((xy)z)a)b=(((yz)a)b)x$)? The danger with this example is that maybe every finite magma satisfies all but finitely many equations in $F$, but that's not obvious to me.

I was asking about semigroups.  That is where people most commonly study pseudovarieties and was the motivation for Eilenberg and Schutzenberger

@BenjaminSteinberg Oops, sorry, I misread your comment.

@BenjaminSteinberg I may have asked the wrong question here, since I'm new to this topic. Do you think something along the lines of "Which pseudovarieties have minimal descriptions" would be a better/more tractable problem?

Maybe.  To be honest I only use pseudoidentity descriptions because they are usually more useful

@BenjaminSteinberg Posted.
